# Octave failing to include parts of a plot when saved to file

Tags: octave

I have a very basic custom boxplot function:

```
function myboxplot(LPercentile, Median, RPercentile, Height, LineWidth, BoxHeight, MarkerColour, MarkerSize)
  hold on
  plot([LPercentile, RPercentile], [Height, Height], 'linewidth', LineWidth, 'color', 'k', 'linestyle', '-');
  plot([LPercentile, LPercentile], [Height - BoxHeight/2, Height + BoxHeight/2], 'linewidth', LineWidth,  'color', 'k', 'linestyle', '-');
  plot([RPercentile, RPercentile], [Height - BoxHeight/2, Height + BoxHeight/2], 'linewidth', LineWidth,  'color', 'k', 'linestyle', '-');  
  plot(Median, Height, 'marker', 'o', 'markersize', MarkerSize, 'markeredgecolor', 'k', 'markerfacecolor', MarkerColour);    
  hold off
end
```

When I use it as intended,

```
>> myboxplot(1,2,3,1,3,1,'g',20); hold on
>> myboxplot(2,3,5,3,3,1,'r',20); hold off
>> axis([0,6,0,4]);
```

it produces the expected result within my octave session:

[image]

But when I attempt to save to a file:

```
>> saveas(gcf,'out.pdf','pdf');
```

it fails miserably:

[image]

This happens regardless of output format (at least between pdf and png).
Is this a bug? Is there a workaround to make the lines visible?
(Note: I have also tried this code in matlab, and matlab saves the file as intended)

---

(using:
GNU Octave Version: 4.0.3
GNU Octave License: GNU General Public License
Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 )
**UPDATE:** Octave 4.0.3 on windows produces the right output, so this is definitely a *"bug"* bug on linux. I will be submitting a bug on the octave tracker, but if anyone knows of any workarounds in the meantime I would be very grateful.

Comment: Thanks, Andy! I'm assuming since it works on my windows installation it probably has something to do with one of the libraries on linux. Maybe something openGL related. 'fltk' gives me the same problem. The 'gnuplot' toolkit works (but it doesn't respect my manual placements, plut it doesn't look that nice). I'll test it on my laptop as well which has different linux distro and see what I get ...

Comment: No change in Mint 18 (= ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: So it looks like this bug was already fixed on default. Can you try the 4.2 release candidate 2 on GNU/Linux? And btw, if you want to debug plotting issues use "eps" as output because it's the intermediate format used for OpenGL toolkits.

Comment: Just installed 4.2.0-rc2 tagged release, problem persists. (rc2 looks very nice though :) )
I'll submit a bug on the tracker then. Thanks, Andy.  (PS I didn't find a similar bug on a basic search on the tracker ... )

Comment: submitted as [bug #49225](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?49225)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a genuine bug relating to one of the libraries octave uses to convert openGL graphics to postscript, rather than the octave base itself, as per the [octave bug submission (bug #49225)](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?49225).

From the now closed bug report:

> "This bug has been fixed in the latest version of gl2ps (1.3.9), but linux mint 17.3 ships with gl2ps 1.3.8. On linux, the workaround is to compile your own version of gl2ps."

I can confirm that installing [libgl2ps1 (1.3.9-4)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libgl2ps1) and [libgl2ps-dev (1.3.9-4)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libgl2ps-dev) and recompiling octave resolved this bug.