# Octave only prints last line segment plotted

Tags: printing, octave, export-to-pdf

I am having trouble creating plot files with octave. When executing

```
imagesc([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,3,1;3,2,3;1,3,1]);
line([0,1,2,3,4],[1.5,1.3,1.7,1.5,1.9]);
print("test.pdf);
```

the bitmap image is displayed correctly in the plot window, with a wiggly line superimposed on top. But the .png file only shows the image from "imagesc", plus the last of the four segments drawn by the "line" command. This happens when printing to .png files as well.

I am using octave 4.2.1 on Windows 10, with the "qt" graphics toolkit. Changing toolkits to "fltk" effects no change, while going to "gnuplot" will trigger some error message about the "imagesc" command which I am currently not interested in.

Does anyone know how to get the file output right?

Comment: This looks like a yet unknown bug in octave (https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?go_report=Apply&group=octave&func=browse&summary=png&chunksz=50&boxoptionwanted=1#options) . Which I can confirm for Windows 7 too. Please file a bug report at savannah.gnu.org.

Comment: Don't know if this is also the case on windows (though it would be easy to check the libgl2ps library used by your octave distribution), but I've had similar problems on linux due to an outdated version of the libgl2ps library used by octave. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39746234/4183191 I suspect this is part of the same problem.

Comment: Georg W., thanks for pointing out savannah.gnu.org. I found a workaround in bug report #51464.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a third dimension to the line coordinates solved my problem. I have implemented the following changes following a workaround found in bug report #51464 on savannah.gnu.org:

```
imagesc([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,3,1;3,2,3;1,3,1]);
line([0,1,2,3,4],[1.5,1.3,1.7,1.5,1.9],[4,4,4,4,4]);
zlim ([0 4]);
print("test.pdf");
```